# animation in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android.I need to know the Basic Animation in Android for View's and View Group's.Can anyone give some Guide lines to learn it !!! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could start by reading the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) to animations

Comment: Actually the link is http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

for future visitors i guess you need to try this [nineoldandroids android animation](http://nineoldandroids.com/#usage)

its so simple to use. dont forget to read the docs.

download the zip, use the src copy to your main folder src folder, or you can make a jar file out of it, or make it a library .. as for me I copied the src to my src.

```
package com.example.titleanimation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import static com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animate;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private ImageView image;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            /*
               to do it like this you need to add import  
               import static com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animate;
            */
    animate(image).setDuration(10000).rotationBy(360);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

happy coding ^^
**NOTE : i tried Tween Engine by Aurielien Ribbon but theres a problem with API 8 , views dont have setX and setY.**

best regards,
Dave

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: correct! , im posting the codes , and if ever the link changes, you can actually get in touch with jake wharton, thats the guy the created actionbar sherlock and the link i posted.